# CSS right-border not displayed

Tags: css, border

On my site http://goo.gl/BcJtC section "about us" I'd like a thin grey border on the right side of my `activity-left` div, to make a separation with `activity-right` div.
Unfortunately with my current code it doesn't work. Any idea?
 Thanks

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="section" id="plan-activite">
   <div id="activity-container">
      <div id="activity-left"><span class="activity-title">About Us</span><br /><img src="images/planet-water.jpg" class="activity-planet" alt="Picture" /></div>
      <div id="activity-right"><p><span class="activity-conclusion">XYZ, khkhkhk, ren natur</span></p><br /><p>XXZ AS was founded 2011sdqsd.</p><br/>
      </div>
   </div>
</div><!--END page3-->
```

**CSS code:**

```
#activity-container {
    width:90%;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    Height:400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    opacity:0.95;
    filter:alpha(opacity=95); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    border: 1px solid #efefef;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) inset; 
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) inset;
}
#activity-left {
    color:#000;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    border-style:solid;
    border-right-color:#666;
    padding:15px;
    width: 30%; 
    float: left;
    position: relative; 
}
#activity-right { 
    font:12px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight:400;
    margin: O auto; 
    padding:15px;
    color:#000;
    width: 60%; 
    float: left;
    position: relative; 
    text-align:justify;
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
    -moz-column-rule: 1px solid #c4c8cc;
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
    -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #c4c8cc;
}
.activity-planet {
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `border: 1px solid #000` to `#activity-left`. It works for me.

Although I would do `border-left: 1px solid #000` for `#activity-right` as this will extend all the way down.

Comment: Actually, just noticed that the border is not going all the way down (there's a few px left at the bottom). Would you know how to fix this? (you can have a look at the link - have uploaded a new version) Thanks

Comment: That is because #activity-right is not as tall as the containing div, add a few more pixels to the height of that until it works (or alternatively, use height: 100%; to have the same height as the containing div

Comment: Have used height:100% but now the line goes outside the container. Is there a way to offset that padding with impacting the text in the DIV? (have uploaded a new version http://goo.gl/BcJtC )

Comment: I would probably suggest just playing with the % (try 95 for example) until you get it right. As the size of the container isn't going to change it shouldnt matter

Answer (score 0):

The border declaration is made up of three parts: `color`, `style` and `width` properties. **Style** and **width** are mandatory, with **color** being optional (inheriting from the text color if not provided).

These properties can be made more specific using the `-left`, `-right`, `-top` and `-bottom` suffixes, as you have done for the **color** property.

So at present, all you are missing is the width declaration in order to have a right-hand border. The trouble with that though, is that since you've set a generic **style** for the whole `<div>`, adding `border-width: 1px`, will give the other 3 sides a border in the default color.

To get around this, you can use the shorthand declarations and give all 3 properties just to the right-hand side at once (`border-right: 1px solid #000;`).